# Plot all variables within a for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot all variables within `X_train1_raw`

```
X_train1_raw.shape
(2039, 17)
```

according to:

```
n_splits = 5
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits = n_splits)

plt.figure(1)
index = 1
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(24,7))
plt.style.use('seaborn-white')
fig.suptitle('', fontsize=20)
fig.tight_layout()
for train_index, val_index in tscv.split(X_train1_raw):
    X_train1, X_val1 = prepare_data.fit_transform(X_train1_raw[train_index]), prepare_data.fit_transform(X_train1_raw[val_index])
    y_train1, y_val1 = prepare_data.fit_transform(y_train1_raw[train_index]), prepare_data.fit_transform(y_train1_raw[val_index])
    plt.subplot(510 + index)

    plt.plot(X_train1[:, 1])
    plt.plot([None for i in X_train1[:, 1]] + [x for x in X_val1[:, 1]])

    plt.plot(X_train1[:, 2])
    plt.plot([None for i in X_train1[:, 2]] + [x for x in X_val1[:, 2]])

    index +=1
plt.show();
```

which results in

[image: only 2nd variable]

So only the second variable is plotted. When I assign the plot-commands to certain axes, it results in an empty plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(24,7))
(...)
for train_index, val_index in tscv.split(X_train1_raw):
    X_train1, X_val1 = prepare_data.fit_transform(X_train1_raw[train_index]), prepare_data.fit_transform(X_train1_raw[val_index])
    y_train1, y_val1 = prepare_data.fit_transform(y_train1_raw[train_index]), prepare_data.fit_transform(y_train1_raw[val_index])
    plt.subplot(510 + index)

    ax[0].plot(X_train1[:, 1])
    ax[0].plot([None for i in X_train1[:, 1]] + [x for x in X_val1[:, 1]])

    ax[1].plot(X_train1[:, 2])
    ax[1].plot([None for i in X_train1[:, 2]] + [x for x in X_val1[:, 2]])

    index +=1
plt.show();
```

which results in

[image: empty]

How can I adjust this to plot all variables in parallel?

Comment: You have typed 'plt.subplot(510 + index)'. Did you check if index goes beyond 5?

Comment: index stops at 5 due to the time series split

Answer (score 0):

I do not have access to your data + I am away from a computer to test it. Still below is my suggestion. I have changed your code slightly. Please do the necessary adjustments.

**using plt.add_subplot()**

```py
n_splits = 5
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits = n_splits)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(24,7))
index = 0
plt.style.use('seaborn-white')
for train_index, val_index in tscv.split(X_train1_raw):
    X_train1, X_val1 = prepare_data.fit_transform(X_train1_raw[train_index]), prepare_data.fit_transform(X_train1_raw[val_index])
    y_train1, y_val1 = prepare_data.fit_transform(y_train1_raw[train_index]), prepare_data.fit_transform(y_train1_raw[val_index])
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(5,2,index*2+1)

    ax1.plot(X_train1[:, 1])
    ax1.plot([None for i in X_train1[:, 1]] + [x for x in X_val1[:, 1]])

    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(5,2,index*2+2)
    ax2.plot(X_train1[:, 2])
    ax2.plot([None for i in X_train1[:, 2]] + [x for x in X_val1[:, 2]])

    index +=1
plt.show()
```

Please let me know if there is any error.